# copying from file to pointer

Tags: c, file, fgets

I'm writting a passing program and I have a little problem.
I want to dynamically allocate memory location with the size of the sentence which is readed from a file. Also this pointer should have this text in contents

When file will have sentence:

> "One two three four five"

Then I want `char*` example with allocated memory location for 25 chars.
And when I would like to print this text on console I want do it by

```
printf("%c", example);
```

Console should look like that:

> One two three four five

I'm doing it like that:

```
char* czyt = (char*)malloc(sizeof(fgets( line/*static variable*/,
                                         500 /*MAX LINE LENGHT*/,
                                         wejscie /*FILE*/ )));
```

But in this case `czyt` doesn't have this sentence and I need to use static variable.

Comment: When you use `sizeof` on a pointer (like the one returned by `fgets`)  you get the size of *the pointer* and not what it points to. if you want to get the length of a string, use `strlen`.

Comment: Yep. That's true. But when I will use strlen, I will still need to use static variable: "line".
I want to czyt has in contents "One two three four five" + memory location for 25 chars.

Comment: By the way, have you thought about what would happen if the `fgets` call fails? Allocating zero bytes may still work, and you simply have no idea that the input operation failed.

Comment: I wonder just how to do it.
I need to write program with will sort alphabetically all the lines and when I will get file
"First line: Ccccc Bbbbb
Second line: Aaaaa"
Then output should look like that:
"First line: Aaaaa
Second line:  Bbbbb Cccccc"

Comment: @TymoteuszPinior - Use Joachim Pileborg's advice, but use it with your pointer, not the line variable

Comment: @TymoteuszPinior `' '` < `'A'`

Comment: You can't print a string with `%c` in `printf()`. It should be `%s`.

Answer (score 0):

If your concern is to solve this without a buffer: It's somewhat unusual. But on a POSIX-like system you could use `stat()` (cf. http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/stat.html).

Less efficient is to use Posix' `lseek()`: `open` the file, seek to the end with `int fileLength = lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_END);` and allocate `fileLength` bytes.

Whatever function you use, it will tell you the size of the file without reading anything so that you can then allocate a buffer of exactly the required size. Don't forget to rewind the file with `lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_SET)` before you read from it, or close it and open again with `fopen()`.

Answer (score -1):

> The most ideal way to sort the lines of file would be to
>   use a dictionary tree. Create a dictionary tree with individual lines
>   and then perform a depth-first traversal.

Here is a simple program that would do a dynamic buffer allocation based on line length( assuming the length of line is not more than 500)

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
        char string[500];
        char *str;

        FILE *in_file = fopen("abc.txt", "r");
        if (in_file == NULL)
        {
                printf("Error file missing\n");
                exit(-1);
        }
        while ( fgets(string, 500, in_file) != NULL)
        {
                str = (char *)  malloc ( sizeof(char) * strlen(string));
                strcpy(str, string);
                printf("%s", str);
        }
        fclose(in_file);
        return 0;
}
```

In case if you want to sort them, you can either use a linked list to store these data or can use an array of pointers (which would hold the pointer address of all the malloc-ed lines) and then sort by manipulating the pointers